'Inner minimum concave hull' in triangle soup
Given an arbitrary 3D model of a house, I want to write a software that helps the user to select one specific air volume. I need that single volume as a manifold shape to calculate room acoustics in that volume/room.
A simple example:
Let's say the model is a single room with walls of some thickness and closed above and below by a polygon (no thickness). I would find multiple closed volumes here (for example, each wall is a closed volume by itself. That's why I plan to let the user select the volume of interest by placing a point somewhere in the 3D space (in the air-filled volume of the room).
Unfortunately, I have not found any research, algorithms, or implementations. Do you know any existing stuff that can be used to find the minimal concave hull around an 'air' point? Even the right wording for describing my problem would help me. I am searching for a hull, but I don't find needles in the haystack of papers about outer hulls around point clouds.
Own thoughts for implementing such an algorithm:
I think I will try to segment the mesh starting from the wall (triangle) closest to the user-selected point.
Then, I build a graph of segments touching each other and iterate and improve from there.

Do you know any existing algorithms that can be used to solve the problem or parts of it?
I haven't found one, but is any CGAL package capable of helping here?
Are there any better sites for discussing these kinds of problems?


I have rewritten my question for better explanation around your 'multiple rooms' question. When no watertight room is found, a future improvement could be to color any openings. Doors and windows should be closed in the model if they are closed in reality (acoustics are changing when you open/close a door/window). This can be taught  to the user.

" I will try to segment the mesh starting from the wall (triangle) closest to the user-selected point. Then, I build a graph of segments touching each other and iterate and improve from there."  This seems sensible.  Have you tied implementing it?  What problems have you hit with your implementation?

The simplest case would be a unit cube with no openings and walls of zero thickness.  In this case, would your input data ( what you called, in an earlier version of your question, a triangle soup ) look like this https://github.com/JamesBremner/so78467648/blob/main/dat/unitcube.txt?

Your suggested algorithm can be made to work.  Snag is that if the input model is very high resolution ( lots a small triangles ) compute time may be an issue.  If you can accept an approximation and want control of compute time, use a ray tracing algorithm: construct a predetermined number of rays in all directions from the start point, find the first triangle each ray hits, and construct your hull from them.

With 'watertight' I mean that the triangles form a volume without openings. I don't 'handle' and don't need to know doors/windows. For the specific aspect of finding the manifold volume, triangles are either wall/door/window..doesn't matter. I have not done any implementation yet, as I hope of your ideas that are better than mine.

I also thought about raytracing first but I will try ‘walking’ the walls as described first. I replaced ‘watertight’ with ‘closed‘ in the question. I ‘kept resisting’ because I had dinner ;)

I think the face normals of your triangles look in different directions (mixed CW and CCW) but your unit cube example is right in principle. It’s a simple test room.

You are right. This is data that I would like my algorithm to digest without problems. I somehow thought your case is meant to be a minimal, ideal case.

Haven't heard from your recently.  Are you still interested in this problem?  FYI I have added some unit tests to my code, including a double walled room ( like your 'simple example')  Here is the unit text code https://github.com/JamesBremner/RoomFinder/blob/3e41b438b93b0e0f77485492b5db0e4ec908ce8b/src/cBuilding.cpp#L131

AS you mention CGAL, you might have a look at Alpha Wrapping.  It works for a non-convex outer hull, but as well for "rooms". You can control the  size of cavities to explore, so you may prevent it going through openings.

Thanks for your suggestion! Alpha Wrapping was one of the things I had a look at. The description says things like 'shrink-wrapping starting from a bounding box'. Are you sure that I can use it to find volumes from inside?

Implement a ray tracing algorithm:
construct a predetermined number of rays in all directions from the start point, find the first triangle each ray hits, and construct your hull from them.
You can check out my C++ code for an application that does this at
https://github.com/JamesBremner/RoomFinder
Here is the declaration of the method that does this work
    /// @brief select hull around air point
    /// @param ap air point
    void selectHull(cxyz ap);

and here is the implementation
void cBuild::selectHull(cxyz ap)
{
    mySelectTriangles.clear();

    // Loop over rays from starting point in all directions
    for (cxyz r : destRays(ap))
    {
        double mindist2 = DBL_MAX;
        cTriangle tmin;

        // loop over triangles
        for (auto &t : myTriangles)
        {

            // check for intersection
            cxyz ip = cxyz::intersectLineTriangle(ap, r, t.myP);
            if (!ip.isValid())
                continue;

            // check for closest intersection with this ray
            double dist2 = ap.dist2(ip);
            if (dist2 < mindist2)
            {
                tmin = t;
                mindist2 = dist2;
            }
        }

        // if triangle found and is novel, add to hull
        if (mindist2 != DBL_MAX)
        {
            bool found = false;
            for (auto &t : mySelectTriangles)
            {
                if (tmin == t)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                mySelectTriangles.push_back(tmin);
        }
    }
}

The rest is implementation of standard 3D computational geometry algorithms.  You can find them in https://github.com/JamesBremner/RoomFinder/blob/main/src/cxyz.h
